# How to dm a specific person with a discord bot in python

Tags: python, discord

I want to make a command that makes my bot send a message to the mentioned person, but this one line of code keeps returning NoneType. how do i fix this?

```
user = client.get_user('user id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_` methods only work when the thing you're getting is already in the cache;  you need to use [`fetch_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_user). As you mentioned it's a command, you should already be within an `async` function.

```py
user = await client.fetch_user(USER_ID)
try:
    await user.send(content="A direct message")
except discord.Forbidden:
    # don't have permissions to dm the user
    # they might have turned dms off from non-friends
    # either pass/continue/return whatever is appropriate
```

You could also use `get_user` in tandem with `fetch_user`.

```py
user = client.get_user(USER_ID)
if not user:
    user = await client.fetch_user(USER_ID)
```

`fetch_user` makes an API call so if you're doing this regularly then you might have the user in the cache from an earlier `fetch`. We can use `get` first to try and limit the API calls (and also make the command process slightly quicker).